# method to solve "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)" is not working

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am getting an error while writing a string to a file.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The thing is i have already cleaned up the string. Not sure why that is not working though

Here is my code to clean up string

```
import string

replace_punctuation = string.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' '*len(string.punctuation))

def clean_text(text):
    try:
        text = text.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    except:
        text = text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        text = text.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    text = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').lower().translate(replace_punctuation)
    text = " ".join(text.split())
    return text

text = "some text with special characters"
text = clean_text(text)
#outfile is an output file
outfile.write(text) #This step is giving error
```

Any idea what i am missing here while cleaning up string?

I know this question has been asked a lot. But my issue is that the most common solution to this problem is

```
text.encode('utf-8')
```

which is not working for me.

I also tried

```
text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

didn't work

Comment: you want an encoded text to write to a file, not a decoded unicode object. When you call `encode('ascii')` on a unicode object with `Ä` it will fail because its not in ascii. Also: don't worry everyone goes through that in python. Excellent talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc

Comment: @SebastianWozny: thanks man. So what would be the solution for this? remove encode with ascii ignore ? PS: checking out that video now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error it is throwing for you. I just tested this in python 2.7.10 on windows:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import string

replace_punctuation = string.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' '*len(string.punctuation))

def clean_text(text):
    try:
        text = text.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    except:
        text = text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        text = text.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    text = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').lower().translate(replace_punctuation)
    text = " ".join(text.split())
    return text

text = "some text öäööäwith special characters"
text = clean_text(text)
print text
with open('test.txt','w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(text)

>>>
some text with special characters
```

The file also contains the same text.

This could be an alternative:

```
from string import ascii_letters, whitespace, punctuation, digits
text = ''.join(c for c in text if c in chain(ascii_letters, whitespace, punctuation, digits)).lower().translate(replace_punctuation)
```

You filter out characters that are not in ascii, so you dont have to worry about unicode.